# Google Maps API remove TRANSIT bars

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google API v3 and its Directions service (searching routes with TRANSIT parameter). Wanna remove all bars (like 513C or 164A) and duno how to do.
Markers were deleted by adding *suppressMarkers:true*. Any solutions with transport bars, please?

[image]

Comment: The suppressInfoWindows option doesn't help.  Might need to create an enhancement request to disable these.  I don't know what to call them either.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution. After receiving response you need to clear

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].steps.transit=null
```